# How to correlate native WebRTC "M" version with branch head?

Tags: webrtc

I am confused by native WebRTC version stamping!  I know that "versions" are named like "Mxxx" (e.g. M103).  I also know that checking out specific "branch heads" is the way to get the source for a particular release/version. But how are the those related?  For instance I just checked out `branch-heads/5162`.  What is the "M" version for that? How can I figure that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebRTC follows the same release cycle as Chromium and the chromium dashboard provides a list of milestones (hence the `M`) and their associated branches:
https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/branches
(it even has nice colors!)

5162 is a daily branch and not actively maintained.

Comment: Sweet!  This is exactly what I was hoping to see.  Thank you!